# jquery.highCheckTree : How to use nested Parent and child relational JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I need to create tree view display with nested data.. but unable to display..

source demo URL : http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Checkbox-Tree-View-highchecktree/

```js
         var mockData= [{
    item:{id:'id', label:'label', checked:false}, 
    chidren:[{
        item:{id:'id2', label:'label2', checked:false}, 
        chidren:[
          {item:{id:'id3', label:'label3', checked:false}
            
          }]
    }]
},
{
    item:{id:'id11', label:'label11', checked:false}, 
    chidren:[{
        item:{id:'id211', label:'label211', checked:false}, 
        chidren:[
          {item:{id:'id311', label:'label311', checked:false}
            
          }]
    }]
}];

            
            $('#tree-container').highCheckTree({
                data: mockData
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Checkbox-Tree-View-highchecktree/css/highCheckTree.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Checkbox-Tree-View-highchecktree/js/highchecktree.js"></script>
     <div id="tree-container"></div>
```

Comment: What is the hierachy that you want? Do you get anything on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only that you are missing the `'l'` in `children`. In all of them. Else it is perfectly fine.

`chidren:[` -> `children:[`

Comment: :( A tough time I should say. Had been breaking my head all this time to discover such a silly one. With no errors in js consle as well.